# Python CustomJS filtering "Contains" instead of "Equals"

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

I'm creating a plot in Bokeh with a MultiChoice Widget to filter my data. I'm using this CustomJS statement to filter my data:

```
enter  var s1 = source.data;
var selected = multi_choice.value;
var new_data= {};
new_data['Acidity']=[];
new_data['Chlorides']=[];
new_data['Density']=[];
new_data['Sulfates']=[];
new_data['Rating']=[];


function containsAny(source,target)
{
    var result = source.filter(function(item){ return target.indexOf(item) > -1});   
    return (result.length > 0);  
}

for (var i = 0; i < s1['Strain'].length; i++) {
        if (containsAny(selected,s1['Strain'][i])) {
            new_data['Acidity'].push(s1['Strain'][i])
            new_data['Chlorides'].push(s1['THC_AVG'][i])
            new_data['Density'].push(s1['CBD'][i])
            new_data['Sulfates'].push(s1['IND'][i])
            new_data['Rating'].push(s1['Rating'][i])}}
table_source.data = new_data
```

This code seems to work just fine, except for the fact that when I type in a string to filter for, it selects ALL of the choices that contain my string, as well as the exact result. I'm fairly certain this is because of my "containsAny" statement for my selection, but cannot successfully change the containsAny to contains "only" or "equals" in the JS.

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: If you only want an exact match you can use `==`, what are you looking for in your filtering?

Comment: Thanks @Caridorc, I did try this but unfortunately couldn’t get the statement to work re “i”, “selected”, and “s1”. Do you know how to set this part up?